# Cannot create or save files on Cloud9

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have an ubuntu  workspace but I can't create files or save them ,I can only create files with linux commands but is not possible to save this is the error I get when I try to save `ERR: Error: EACCES, open 'filename.php'`

Comment: Do you have disk space left in your workspace? You can find out by running the `quota` command on the terminal. Also, you should write to community.c9.io with details about this

Comment: Yes I have disk space

Comment: Is this issue still occurring for you? If so, can you write in to support@c9.io or community.c9.io?

Comment: No because I decided to continue working on local instead cloud 9

Comment: This happened to me after `chown -R root:root`. The solution was `chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu`.

Comment: This chown command fixed my issues with saving/creating files.